# Problem with Server Class Socket in JAVA [Eclipse]

Tags: java, eclipse, serversocket

I've tried to develop this Server in Java with Eclipse, but when I run it says me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
```

I don't understand where I should insert this "}" because I've just tried to close the class with "};" but it persists... thanks in advance!

This is the code:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ServerStr {
    ServerSocket server = null;
    Socket client = null;
    String stringaRicevuta = null;
    String stringaModificata = null; 
    BufferedReader inDalClient;
    DataOutputStream outVersoClient; 

    public Socket attendi() {
        try {
            System.out.println("1 SERVER partito in esecuzione..partito.");
            server = new ServerSocket(6789);
            client = server.accept();
            server.close();
            inDalClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            outVersoClient = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Errore durante l'istanza del server");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return client;
    }

    public void comunica() {
        try {
            System.out.println("3 benvenuto client, scrivi una frase e la trasformo in maiuscolo. Attendo...");
            stringaRicevuta = inDalClient.readLine();
            System.out.println(" e ricevuta la stringa dal cliente" + stringaRicevuta);
            stringaModificata = stringaRicevuta.toUpperCase();
            System.out.println(" invio la stringa modificata al client...");
            outVersoClient.writeBytes(stringaModificata + '\n');
            System.out.println("9 SERVER: fine elaborazione... buonanotte!");
            client.close();
        }
        finally {
        }
    };

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ServerStr servente = new ServerStr();
        servente.attendi();
        servente.comunica();
    }
```

Comment: Fix your indentation (or get your editor/IDE to do it for you).

Comment: How can i do it?

Comment: There should be another `}` at the end. If your code was properly indented, this would be glaringly obvious.

Comment: Ok now it works but there is an error: "Unhandled exception type IOException at this line: "stringaRicevuta=inDalClient.readLine();"... why this?

Comment: The method being called can throw an IOException, and you are not catching or otherwise handling it.